# How to define a variable "N" type in C when N it is an input to C and its also defined by an input function( N will prompt the user for input)

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, logic, cs50

I am still new to programming and very very new to C programming, so please pardon me if my question seems ridiculous.

I am learning about functions and function calls and I am trying to follow what the instructor is doing but with a little addition.
The instructor did the following:

- The instructor defined a function cough -- (void cough(int N))
- Called the function in main using only one line of code
- The program prints out cough a hard coded number of times on screen i.e cough(3) will print cough     3 times.

I am trying to:

- Define a function cough -- (void cough(int))
- Call the function in main using only one line of code
- The program should print out cough N number of times on screen, but should be gotten when program starts with a prompt e.g "How many coughs?"

The C(c99) I am using has a library cs50.h (from online course cs50), that provides a code to get integer input.
After searching and trying I have successfully done as below:

After including the cs50 library
int N = get_int("How many coughs")
cough(N)

And also
cough(get_int("How many coughs"))

I am only wondering why can't I successfully use below code in C without getting an error. Why can't N be generated from the function?

The error I got is --- use of undeclared identifier 'N'

```
void cough(int N);
int main(void)
{
    cough(N);
}

void cough(int N)
{
    N = get_int("How many coughs?\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("cough\n");
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading the long story and providing guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a program in C, you can only identifiers that have been defined previously ... or, of course, when you are defining them.

So let's work with your code line by line

```
void cough(int N);
```

`void` already defined: a language keyword
`cough` it's being (tentatively) defined here
`int` already defined: a language keyword
`N` it's being (tentatively) defined here. This definition is valid until the next close parenthesis because it's a parameter definition

```
int main(void) {
```

`main` is being defined here

```
    cough(N);
```

`cough` was (tentatively) defined before, so it's OK: compiler knows it is a function, the previous tentative definition and the actual definition cannot change that.
`N` OOPS!!! not defined before, not a keyword, compiler stops with error :)

---

You could define `cough()` to take no arguments, though

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int cough(void);
int main(void)
{
    cough();
}

void cough(void)
{
    int N = get_int("How many coughs?\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("cough\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a whole lot for the step-by-step guide.
Bruno helped alot with his answer and guide and you helped make me understand even more with the compiler explanation.
I truly appreciate the time taking to help me get the concept.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

> I am only wondering why can't I successfully use below code in C without getting an error.
>
> use of undeclared identifier 'N'

because in

```
int main(void)
{
    cough(N);
}
```

*N* is not defined in *main* as a local variable, and it is not a global variable too, so you cannot compile your code

> but should be gotten when program starts with a prompt e.g "How many coughs?"

so

> ```
> N = get_int("How many coughs?\n");
> ```

must be moved in *main*

Finally you want something like that :

```
void cough(int N);
int main(void)
{
    cough(get_int("How many coughs?\n"));
    return 0;
}

void cough(int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("cough\n");
    }
}
```

Note your `printf` prints a constant string, so you can replace it by `puts("cough");` which is a little faster because `printf` search for '%' for nothing in that case

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain with details and help guide.

I also value the extra insight on using puts instead of printf, I have seen it along with scanf and often wondered what to use, I will start using puts from now whenever I am to print out a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but I didn't use `get_int()`

```
void cough(int N);
int main(void)
{
    int N = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &N );
    cough(N);
}

void cough(int N)
{
    printf("How many coughs?\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("cough\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `N` in `main` (which, by the way, is totally independent of `N` in `cough`.  For example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int N = 5;
    cough(N);
{
```

As an alternative, you can use `cough(5)` or define `N` to be global.